# Comparison of columns in two files and appending the first file

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a file : emp.txt

```
21356 suresh 12/12/2012
23511 ramesh 11/06/2011
31456 biswajit 09/08/2013
53134 archan  06/02/2009
```

first field:- employee id, 2nd field is name and third field is date of joining

HR gives a list of employees who have been moved out of the company.
Let's suppose i get a text file from hr:-

```
ramesh
archan
```

I need to compare it with second column of the original employee list and which ever matches , employee list will be updated

```
21356 suresh 12/12/2012
23511 ramesh_terminated  11/06/2011
31456 biswajit 09/08/2013
53134 archan_terminated  06/02/2009
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} ($2 in a){$2=$2"_terminated"}1' hr.txt empt.txt
21356 suresh 12/12/2012
23511 ramesh_terminated 11/06/2011
31456 biswajit 09/08/2013
53134 archan_terminated 06/02/2009
```